# Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown database 'test_db'. I keep getting this error even though I programatically created the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Here is the code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$usrname   = "root";
$pwd = "";
$db = "test_db";
// connect to the database
$conn= mysqli_connect($servername, $usrname, $pwd,$db);
if (!$conn){
    die('connection failed' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
// Create database
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test_db";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Database created successfully<br>";
} else {
  echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
?>
```

I am not sure what is going on as I am sure i made no errors while typing. As it keeps showing me that there is an unknown database despite the fact i made a CREATE DATABASE statement.
I do not know if there is something else i need to do but by all measures the code should work.
It is supposed to echo the "Database created successfully" or the error message.

Comment: You can not create database when you connection is null or setup is failed. Create database using shell or connect to other database to create MySQL connection.

Comment: Don't connect with a DB parameter `mysqli_connect($servername,$usrname,$pwd)`, then use `mysqli_select_db($db)` once the DB exists, assuming your credential has permission to call `CREATE DATABASE`

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$usrname   = "root";
$pwd = "";
$db = "test_db";

// connect to the database
$conn= mysqli_connect($servername, $usrname, $pwd);

// Create database
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE $db";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Your code is fine, You just have to remove $db from mysqli_connect().
Because you are trying to use a database "test_db" which doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score -2):

$conn= mysqli_connect($servername, $usrname, $pwd,$db);

You are trying to connect to a database that did not initially exist, so you get a fatal error.

Try creating new database using try catch blocks

```
try{
$conn= mysqli_connect($servername, $usrname, $pwd,$db);
}cath(Exception $e){
//your code
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).